# Is there a way to receive macOS events while users hold down a mouse button?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Having a SwiftUI `slider`.
The user keeps on dragging it around.
While dragging, the user also presses the `Option` key.

I want to change the user interface based on the keyboard modifier flag change (e.g. the Option key). However, it seems the main event loop is blocked while dragging the slider or even when having a mouse button pressed.

When using the `NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(mathing:handler)` to get notified of the `Option` keypress, the handler does not even get called while the user drags the slider.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

I would also love to understand why the problem exists in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up using a timer block checking and publishing changes of the keyboard modifier flags.

```
import Cocoa
import Combine

/**
    Publishers for keyboard events.

    The modifiers are checked regularly by a Timer running on the Main `RunLoop` in `.common` mode
    to ensure the modifiers are detected even when having mouse button pressed down
    (which normally blocks the run loops on the main thread which are not in `common` mode).

    The `NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents` cannot be used because the handler is not executed
    for nested-tracking loops, such as control tracking (e.g. when a mouse button is down).
 */
public class KeyboardEvents {
    /// Broadcasts keyboard flag changes (e.g. keys like Option, Command, Control, Shift, etc.)
    public let modifierFlagsPublisher: AnyPublisher<NSEvent.ModifierFlags?, Never>

    private let modifierFlagsSubject = PassthroughSubject<NSEvent.ModifierFlags?, Never>()
    private var timer: Timer!

    public init() {
        modifierFlagsPublisher = modifierFlagsSubject.removeDuplicates().eraseToAnyPublisher()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [unowned self] _ in
            modifierFlagsSubject.send(NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags)
        }

        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }

    deinit {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```